# Manually order the set fails in UpsetR

Tags: r, ggplot2, upsetr

*This question was also asked on [Biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/9547684/)*

I have tried to use UpsetR to visualise the input file, which can be found [here](https://cloudstor.aarnet.edu.au/plus/s/OupXC8rF2bDFtRV). How is it possible to make UpsetR accept an order defined in `sets=c("Nlab", "NQLD", "Ngla", "Nsyl", "Ntom", "Ntab", "Natt", "Cann", "Stub", "Slyc", "Vvin", "Atha")`?

**with keep.order = T**
[image: with keep.order = T]

**with keep.order = F**
[image: with keep.order = F]

```
> library("UpSetR")
> orthogroups_df<- read.table("orthogroups.GeneCount.tsv",  header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
> #All species
> selected_species <- colnames(orthogroups_df)[2:(ncol(orthogroups_df) -1)] 
> selected_species
 [1] "Atha" "Cann" "NQLD" "Natt" "Ngla" "Nlab" "Nsyl" "Ntab" "Ntom" "Slyc" "Stub" "Vvin"
> head(orthogroups_df)
  Orthogroup Atha Cann NQLD Natt Ngla Nlab Nsyl Ntab Ntom Slyc Stub Vvin Total
1  OG0000000    0    0  965    0    0    3    0    0    0    0    0    0   968
2  OG0000001    0    1    3    0    0  448    0    0    0    0    0    0   452
3  OG0000002    0    1  313    0    0  120    1    0    1    0    0    0   436
4  OG0000003    0   93   15   21   46   16   33   63   36   25   39   26   413
5  OG0000004    1   42    2   34  109    6    8  154   11    9    4    0   380
6  OG0000005    0    2   61    1   34   44   91   70   43   20    1    0   367
> ncol(orthogroups_df)
[1] 14
> orthogroups_df[orthogroups_df > 0] <- 1
> # we only show intersections of interest ,  
> intersections=list(list(selected_species),
+                    list("NQLD", "Ngla", "Natt", "Nlab", "Nsyl", "Ntab", "Ntom"),
+                    list("Stub", "Slyc"),
+                    list("Atha", "Vvin"),
+                    list("Ntab", "Nsyl", "Ntom"),
+                    list("Nlab", "NQLD", "Ngla"), 
+                    list("Nlab", "NQLD", "Nsyl"), 
+                    list("Nlab", "Ngla", "Nsyl"), 
+                    list("NQLD", "Nsyl", "Ngla"))
> upset(orthogroups_df, 
+       text.scale = c(1.4),
+       sets=c("Nlab", "NQLD", "Ngla", "Nsyl", "Ntom", "Ntab", "Natt", "Cann", "Stub", "Slyc", "Vvin", "Atha"), 
+       order.by = "freq",
+       keep.order=T, 
+       intersections = intersections, 
+       sets.x.label="Total number of orthogroups", 
+       mainbar.y.label = "Number of orthogroups")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible that `upset` is using factor levels for ordering, which is the default approach for ggplot2. If this is the case, then it can be fixed by converting the variable to a factor, and using an explicit level definition:

```
sets <- factor(sets, levels=sets)
```

For your specific example:

```
upSets <- c("Nlab", "NQLD", "Ngla", "Nsyl", "Ntom", "Ntab", "Natt", "Cann", "Stub", "Slyc", "Vvin", "Atha")
upSets <- factor(upSets, levels=upSets)
upset(orthogroups_df, 
   text.scale = c(1.4),
   sets=upSets, 
   order.by = "freq",
   keep.order=T, 
   intersections = intersections, 
   sets.x.label="Total number of orthogroups", 
   mainbar.y.label = "Number of orthogroups")
```